# Selectbox two properties

Tags: forms, symfony

I am creating a selectbox with data from DB. I have got

```
      $builder->add('user', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'User:',
        'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:User',
        'query_builder' => function($repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.surename', 'ASC');
        },
        'property' => 'name','data'=>'id'
    ))
```

But instead of showing only name, I want to show surename and name in selectbox. It is dummy question, but I am not able to find answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option would be to implement `__toString()` in your `User` entity:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->surename.' '.$this->name ? '';
}
```

And then remove the option `property` from your form type:

```
$builder->add('user', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'User:',
        'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:User',
        'query_builder' => function($repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.surename', 'ASC');
        }
    ))
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property